# ORB with AGAST Detector

Tags: image-processing, feature-detection, orb

I would like to know whether I can use ORB descriptor with AGAST detector for an android based application.

I know that BRISK uses AGAST detector for detecting the keypoints. Can I implement AGAST with ORB?

Does it work much efficient than ORB Detector/Descriptor.

Please enlighten me on this.

Thanks